# Hide certain Event fields in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've been reading the fullcalendar docs for hours and checking the demos provided but I can't see if this is possible or not.

I'm currently getting events from a Google Calendar, that come with a bunch of fields, for instance:

```
{
    "status": "confirmed",
    "kind": "calendar#event",
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2015-06-29T17: 00: 00+02: 00"
    },
    "created": "2015-06-27T15: 29: 09.000Z",
    "iCalUID": "grmb2ff27hh4ppvk0o7lfclimc@google.com",
    "reminders": {
        "useDefault": "True"
     },
     "htmlLink": "https: //www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=Z3JtYjJmZjI3aGg0cHB2azBvN2xmY2xpbWMgZGV2LmFsZWphbmRyb3ZpbGxhbWFyaW5AbQ",
    "sequence": 0,
    "updated": "2015-06-27T15: 29: 11.144Z",
    "summary": "flowerpower",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2015-06-29T14: 00: 00+02: 00"
    },
    "etag": "2870837902288000",
    "organizer": {
        "self": "True",
        "displayName": "AlejandroVillamarin",
        "email": "dev.alejandrovillamarin@gmail.com"
    },
    "creator": {
        "self": "True",
        "displayName": "AlejandroVillamarin",
        "email": "dev.alejandrovillamarin@gmail.com"
    },
    "id": "grmb2ff27hh4ppvk0o7lfclimc"
}
```

While I want to keep this data, and even send it to fullcalendar through an ajax call, I only want to display "some" of those fields in the calendar itself...how can I do that? I can always use 2 arrays, but it looks odd that the other than that spectacular fullcalendar library does not provide methods to customise the fields to be shown in the each calendar event.

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: what about hiding fields through jquery/javascript/css?

Comment: That's an option, but I will end up quicker by showing what elements I want to :D, there must be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used the FullCalendar [eventRender event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) in conjunction with jQuery to control such things.

Here is an example from a recent project of mine:

```
$(targetElement).fullCalendar({
    events: function (start, end, callback) {
        // code to grab events
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        // 'event' will have all the fields that you want
        // add css class 'label' and display status of event
        element.find('.fc-event-title').addClass('label').append('STATUS ' + event.status);

        var view = $(targetElement).fullCalendar('getView');
        if (view.name === "agendaDay") {
            // day view specific stuff here
        }

        if (view.name === "agendaWeek") {
            // week view specific stuff here
        }
    }
});
```

I use this kind of appending of data in conjunction with the [title property of an event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/).

Comment: element.find('.fc-event-title').addClass('label').append('STATUS ' + event.status) does not seem to add any class to the event...besides do I need to get the view yes or yes?

Comment: Did you check and see that you had an item with the class of 'fc-event-title'? They changed the CSS class names in 2.1.0 version so check in your browser's developer tools / inspector to grab the right one. I think newer versions use 'fc-event' instead.